# alternative words to "denote"

Tags: word-usage

Consider this sentence

> I have a friend that works as an architect.

I am aware that this is a relative clause. To analyze it, I guess I could say

> "that" **denotes** the "friend"

I could also say

> "that" **represents** the "friend"

or

> "that" **refers to** the "friend"

In this context, "represent", "refer to" are alternative words to "denote". Besides which, are there other words could be used that way? For example are "point to" and "link to" appropriate alternative words to "denote" in this case?

Comment: *Points to, links, represents, refers to, denotes,...* are all relatively "technical" terms for the context. In practice, most native speakers in most casual contexts would probably just use ***means*** or plain ***is***. Or for a non-technical term embodying that "indirection", ***stands for***.

Comment: I point out that "that" in the example sentence is not strictly grammatical. It should be "who."

Comment: @JeffMorrow per Cambridge Dictionary, "that" could stand for people, it is just informal, not grammatically incorrect. Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: Of the choices given, I would prefer "refers to" in that context. Or you could say that "friend is the referent (or antecedent) of 'that'".

Comment: @WXJ96163 I think we are just disagreeing about semantics. I said "not strictly grammatical;" Cambridge said "informal." With that said, I personally avoid using "that" instead of "who" or "whom" in writing; it may be viewed as stylistically sloppy or insultingly dehumanizing or both.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I got it. I hadn't thought about that before, but now I have. I've learned a lot in our discussion. Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have been of help.