# “Am I misunderstanding” vs. "Do I misunderstand"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts ([alternative words to "denote"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/241150/109190)), an answerer says

> "that" in the example sentence is not strictly grammatical. It should be "who."

[image]

And I replied

> per Cambridge Dictionary, "that" could stand for people, it is just informal, not grammatically incorrect. **Am I misunderstanding that**?

In this context, should I say the one above or the following

> ... Do I misunderstand that?

or something else? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: More idiomatically, perhaps, ***Have I misunderstood that**?*

Comment: I think "am I misunderstanding that" works just as well.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thx, "just as well" means "as well as 'Have I misunderstood that'"?

Comment: And as well as "Do I misunderstand that?". I will say that the present continuous has a more modern, maybe colloquial feeling to it.